# Difference b/w Specification and implementation

Tags: java

Copy pasted from a site :

To persist a java class using JPA. 
The first step is to qualify this java class as an entity. 
This is done by marking the class with @Entity annotation. 
Marking a class with @Entity annotation will tell to the persistence engine that objects created from this class can use the support of JPA to make them persistent.

[A persistence engine or a persistence provider is nothing but an implementation of the Java Persistence API. Java Persistence API is just a specification from Sun and not an implementation and vendors are free to implement their own persistent framework following the JPA specification. Thus, JPA provided a pluggable interface, where more and more implementations can easily be associated with it at run-time.]

Can someone explain to me the last paragraph with regard to specification and implementation in technical as well as in layman language.
Furthermore, what does it mean ...JPA provided a pluggable interface, where more and more implementations can easily be associated with it at run-time...

Answer (score 3):

JPA is a standard, it defines APIs, annotations, expected behaviours. Hibernate or Eclipselink are implementations of the standard (libraries/jars).

They actually provide the functionality defined on the standard, the standard itself is just a written specification approved as a JSR - Java Request Specification by an approval committee.

To make it more concrete:

- this is JPA, the standard - [PDF](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/persistence-2_0-final-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1398004770_e1e10246c2bdd035f6677ce2e9eeb1e0)
- and this is Hibernate, an implementation of the standard - libraries available [here](http://hibernate.org/orm/downloads/)

Answer (score 1):

Specification means that it gives a lower level framework like to make a class to be treated as a Table using its @Entity annotation. But the the actual CRUD operation functianality is exposed in terms of interfaces so that any third party can use its  own approach to to save the data or doing CRUD.

"vendors are free to implement their own persistent framework", here vendors are like hibernate, spring-data, to put another framework on the top of JPA for giving its own CRUD.

JPA only give a very low level abstraction in the form a predefined frameworks, some things are predefined like @Entity by it while upper level operations are opened through pluggable interfaces so that  third party will handle the query execution.

For more clarification when you use hibernate for mongoDB and Morphia for mongoDB, then you will find mapping is same in both which is common and its JPA while the CRUD syntax and integrations various since hibernate and Morphia are vendors for JPA